# How to integrate aframe to my project ANGULAR-CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, aframe

Hello try integrating aframe in the following way:

1. `npm install aframe --save`
2. setup the `angular-cli.json`

   ```
   "scripts": ["../node_modules/aframe/dist/aframe-master.js"]
   ```
3. Download the typings from https://github.com/devpaul/aframe-typings/blob/master/src/AFRAME.d.ts
4. setup the `tsconfig.json`

   ```
   "files":["typings/AFRAME.d.ts"]
   ```

And I get the following error:
**Cannot find namespace 'THREE'**

Answer (score 1):

In `src/polyfills.ts` you can `import 'aframe';` before you `import 'zone.js/dist/zone'`